# how to identify the problem about under replica blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, hdp

we installed small HDP cluster with one data-node machine

HDP version is `2.6.5` and ambari version is `2.6.1`

so this is new cluster that contain two name-node with only one data-node ( worker machine )

the interesting behavior that we see is that increasing of `under replica` on ambari dashboard , for now the number is  `15000` under replica blocks

as we know the most root cause of this problem is network issues between name node to data-node

but this isn't the case in our hadoop cluster

we can also decrease the under replica by the following procedure

```
su - <$hdfs_user>

bash-4.1$ hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' >> /tmp/under_replicated_files 

-bash-4.1$ for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files`; do echo "Fixing $hdfsfile :" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done
```

**but we not want to do it because under replica problem should not happens from beginning**

and maybe need to tune some HDFS parameters , but we not sure about this

please let us know about any advice that can help us

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If under replicated blocks problem happening since the install of the cluster, check following property:-

```
dfs.replication
```

This decided how many replica needs to be created, if you have `one datanode` then this should be set to `1`

From the metrics page everything looks fine to me,

Comment: what is the suggestion for  example for 2 or 3 datanode?

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: dose dfs.replication is equal to "block replication" ?

Comment: what I mean is if  I set dfs.replication=1 when I have one datanode , then what is the policy when we have more datanode machines?

Comment: just for your information I see now that dfs.replication is actually "Block replication" , so if I set it to 1 , then we not have backup for data and this is risky way

Comment: Right now, you dont have any backups for current blocks as you only have one datanode. Recommended datanodes are 3. At any given point cluster should have 3 datanodes. As we have only one and replication value is set to 3, hence the under replicated blocks.